# Why does the main function work with no return value?

Tags: c++

This question is out of curiosity; while writing a main for a test program, I returned nothing from `main`(no `return` statement in `main`). But I declared main as `int main()`. And it compiled successfully.

Where as if there is any other function written with a `int` return type and actually not returning an `int`,I would get an error

> 'Function name' must return value

So why compiler doesn't complain the same for `main` function?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: yes @Alex1985,my question was why C++ allows main to compile with no return value even though we have specified return type

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Normally it is not allowed for the control flow to reach the end of a non-void function without returning something. The `main` function is handled differently, as specified in the standard.

From http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2960.pdf:

**§ 3.6.1/5**

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return
>   statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

As for the rationale, I'm not sure, honestly. If someone knows, please add it to my answer or as a comment.

Comment: I looked it up. I believe this was introduced with C99, and apparently the C99 rationale is defect. It has comments for 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup, then labels the next chapter 5.1.2.3 Program execution. It should have been 5.1.2.2. As a consequence of this, the rationale for Program termination that should have been in the real chapter 5.1.2.3, has gone missing in action. Thus, main allows no return code in C99 _and there exists no rational reason why_.

Comment: I can't think of no other rationale than that of maintaining compatibility with the corpus of C/C++ source codes that had existed prior to standardization. C was very lax in its early years.

Comment: @Lundin that's excellent, thank you. I've been wondering about this for a long time myself.

Comment: @Lundin If that's true,then I feel sad about it or if like Andrey mentioned it is for compatibility reasons then makes sense.

Comment: The reason for it is **not** backward compatibility; this was a new idea introduced in C++98, and the idea was to make it easier to teach beginners by not having to write and explain `return 0;` in `main`.

Comment: I actually looked up the C90 standard and the clause **was** there. Actually, the section 2.1.2 "Execution Environments" is pretty much the same as the section 5.1.2 "Execution Environments" of C99. And I am pretty sure that C++98 also did have that clause. So it was surely not in C99 that this rule was introduced.

Comment: @ach: I know it's been a time, but... are you sure you had the right document? The ANSI/ISO 9899:1990 I have here has a section *2 Normative references*, which isn't what we're looking for, and section *5.1.2.2.3 Program termination* just like C99. And it states there that (emphasis mine) "if the main function executes a return that specifies no value, the termination status returned to the host environment is **undefined**". I guess they preferred a well-defined EXIT_SUCCESS over an undefined return state, which is good enough for me. But the "implicit `return 0;`" wasn't there in C89/90.

Comment: @DevSolar Now that more than 6 years have passed, I am not sure of anything...

Comment: This was introduced in C++98. They probably thought that this makes C++ a "better C" in one more regard: C code ported to C++ will have one less bug.  C99 then followed probably as a matter of compatibility with C++.

Comment: You cannot underestimate the vast amount of ignorance out there about details like the concept of termination status. Large numbers of programs use `void main`, and those that use `int main` don't bother returning anything.  On some platforms, termination status means little, like Microsoft Windows. A program launched from Explorer, terminated by the user closing its window, might have a termination status at the Win32 API level, but nothing cares about it.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, `int main()` can be left without a return value at which point it defaults to returning 0.

> 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination
>
> 1 If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with
>   int, a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent
>   to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main
>   function as its argument;11) reaching the } that terminates the main
>   function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible
>   with int, the termination status returned to the host environment is
>   unspecified.

But you should be better of using  `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` for return from `main()`.

> Even though you're returning an int, some OSes (Windows) truncate the
>   returned value to a single byte (0-255).       Unix does the same, as do
>   most other operating systems probably.Returning anything other than
>   EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE is asking for trouble

A Quote from [GNU Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Exit-Status)

> Some non-POSIX systems use different conventions for exit status
>   values. For greater portability, you can use the macros EXIT_SUCCESS
>   and EXIT_FAILURE for the conventional status value for success and
>   failure, respectively. They are declared in the file stdlib.h.
>
> — Macro: int EXIT_SUCCESS This macro can be used with the exit
>   function to indicate successful program completion.
>
> On POSIX systems, the value of this macro is 0. On other systems, the
>   value might be some other (possibly non-constant) integer expression.
>
> — Macro: int EXIT_FAILURE This macro can be used with the exit
>   function to indicate unsuccessful program completion in a general
>   sense.
>
> On POSIX systems, the value of this macro is 1. On other systems, the
>   value might be some other (possibly non-constant) integer expression.
>   Other nonzero status values also indicate failures. Certain programs
>   use different nonzero status values to indicate particular kinds of
>   "non-success". For example, diff uses status value 1 to mean that the
>   files are different, and 2 or more to mean that there was difficulty
>   in opening the files.

Comment: _But you should be better of using EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE for return from main()_ - Care to elaborate?

Comment: @ComicSansMS - Because it exists for a reason in `stdlib.h`

Comment: @ComicSansMS -  I have added the required explanations on the topic to my answer.

Comment: Your quote (btw it would be nice if you could give a source for that) makes sense when considering returning an `int` literal versus returning one of the `EXIT_*`s. It does _not_ address the case of using the default return vs explicitly returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`. So I'm still not convinced :)

Comment: Default return in most cases return 0 or 1 (int) which could cause problems if the OS or calling process expects value different to it. SO for portability it is better to use platform independent value `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`

Comment: Did some digging into the standard: `return 0`, both implicitly and explicitly is equivalent to calling `exit(0)` (§3.6.1,5), which in turn is equivalent to calling `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` (§18.5 C++; §7.22 C). In both cases it is the responsibility of the compiler to ensure portability (ibid.), so it makes no difference at all whether you use `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `return 0` or omit the return completely. No such guarantees are given for non-zero return codes though, so there the use of `EXIT_FAILURE` might at least theoretically increase portability.

Comment: Alright!! I quit the argument! Anyways I still think `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` as more stable cross platform.