# GCC misses some errors or warnings

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider this copy constructor of a template class which has an error:

```cpp
MyClass( MyClass const& other )
  : m_x( other.n_x )  // typo: should be `other.m_x`.
{
  // does something
}
```

Or this copy assignment operator overload which does not return anything (`return-type` warning):

```cpp
MyClass& operator=( MyClass const& other )
{
   // does something
   // WARNING: with no `return *this`.
}
```

It has happened several times that GCC compiles the code without any error/warning at first, and later after some changes on other parts of the code, it complains about an issue that it was already there (mostly in constructors or assignment operators as far as I remember).

Does GCC ignores template functions or member function of a template class that are not instantiated throughout the code completely? What is happening under the hood?

I am using GCC 9.3 and GCC 10.1 with `-O3 -Wall -Wpedantic -Werror`.

**UPDATE**
As @someprogrammerdude suggested, here is a minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
template< typename T >
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass( T x ) : m_x( x ) { };
  MyClass( MyClass const& other )
    : m_x( other.n_x )
  {
    std::cout << "in copy constructor" << std::endl;
  }

  MyClass& operator=( MyClass const& other )
  {
    this->m_x = other.m_x;
  }

  T m_x;
};
```

and here is the sample usage which compiles fine as is. But uncommenting some parts gives an error or warning.

```cpp
int main()
{
  MyClass< int > c( 2 );
  std::cout << c.m_x << std::endl;

  /* Uncommenting these lines gives an error in constructor.
   * error: ‘const class MyClass<int>’ has no member named ‘n_x’*/
  //MyClass< int > d = c;
  //std::cout << d.m_x << std::endl;

  /* Uncommenting these lines gives a warning in copy assignment operator.
   * error: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type] */
  //MyClass< int > d( 3 );
  //d = c;
  //std::cout << d.m_x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It is clearer to me now when I created this example. So, there would be no check at all if it is not instantiated?

Comment: Templates needs to be instantiated to detect things like wrong member variables. Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: It depends on what `m_x` and `n_x` are. If both members exist and have the same type the code would be valid. Concerning the second snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474578/gcc-4-8-3-does-not-spot-missing-return-keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC checks templates only by static checker unless they were instantiated. Standard doesn't require even that.

This is possible if your template class is derived from other template. It is not known if that template will have a specialization with such member or not.

E.g. this code is still valid

```
template <template <class> class T, class V>
struct A {
    V m_x;
};

template <template <class> class T, class V>
struct B : A <T, V>
{
   V t;
    
   V getY() { return this->m_y; } 
  // the `this->` is needed exactly because `m_y` wasn't declared
    
   B(B& a) : t(a.m_y) {}
};
```

because it may be followed by and used only with this specialization:

```
template <class V>
struct A<std::complex, V> {
    V m_x;
    V m_y;
};
```

In your particular example `other.n_x` is marking `n_x` as being dependent on template parameters of `MyClass` (similar to `this->` idiom), so it is possible that `n_x` would exist at later point. If it won't exist at point of substitution and instantiation, then it would produce compile error, but not before.

Comment: Thanks. I totally missed the inheritance case which makes sense to not check semantics when the template parameter are not known yet.

Answer (score 1):

Class template members are instantiated on-demand, separately from the class itself. It's how the language works. Template code is *compiled* when it is instantiated; until then the source is simply *parsed*, which does not verify semantics, only some basic structure syntax (such as matching brackets, parentheses, etc).

`MyClass`'s copy constructor will be instantiated the first time an object of that type is copied, or never if it's never copied.

You can ask the compiler to instantiate all template members for a certain type using [explicit instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation) syntax:

```
template class MyClass<int>;  // explicit instantiation
```

Note: an optimizing linker (such as g++) will eliminate unused code so this won't increase the binary size, only the compilation time will increase slightly.