# Is there any default return type for a function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have recently read that the default return type for all functions in C++ is `int`. Googling this does not help me to confirm this.

So :

1. Is really the default return type for all functions in C++ `int` ?
2. If not, then does any such default return type exists for functions in C++ ? If so, then what is it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. Is really the default return type for all functions in C++ `int`?

No.

> 2. If not, then does any such default return type exists for functions in C++ ?

No.

---

Let let the compiler help you out. If you try to do something along the following lines,

```
noReturnType(int a, int b)
{
   std::cout << a + b << "\n";
}
```

you'll get e.g.

> ```
> error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
> noReturnType(int a, int b)  
> ^
> ```

which can be mitigated by adding `void` in front of the function declaration/definition (or whatever type you intend to return). A possible chance of being confused is the ability to let the compiler *deduce* the return type. This example compiles just fine under C++14:

```
auto deduceReturnType(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b; // return type is int
}
```

But this has nothing to do with a default return type, nor can you omit the `auto` here.

Comment: There is an exception in the latest c++11/14, You need not specify the return for ` main` function. [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293642/c-why-main-works-with-no-return-value)

Comment: @ErikNielsen No. That post says you can omit `return ...;`, not the return type.

Comment: Yes, you are right!. What I mean, If we omit, the compiler does not complain about the compilation error, compiler consider, if the main function without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

Comment: Thanks @lubgr for your help.

Answer (score 2):

K&R C had implicit `int`.

```
//assumed to return int
main(argc, argv) 
    char *argv[];
    //not declaring argc's type so it's implicitly assumed to be int
{ return 0; }
```

ANSI C and C++ don't have it.

Comment: Hello @PSkocik, currently I use the ANSI C++ for writing my programs. Thanks a lot for helping me out. Every piece of information is useful for me as I am currently a beginner in C++.