# Why is int x{ y = 5 } possible?

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration, assignment-operator

```
int main() {
    int y;
    int x{ y = 5 };
    //x is 5
}
```

How is this possible, since y = 5 is not a calculable expression?

Also, why doesn't the compiler or IDE complain about main() not returning an int?

Comment: `y = 5` _is_ an expression, and it has value `5`. Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: With regards to the missing `return` of `main`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293642/c-why-main-works-with-no-return-value).

Comment: Better yet, remove the second question. One *single* question per question is the preferred model on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Perhaps you should redefine question to why `y = 5` yields 5 here. Possibility of assignment operators to return something is indeed a bizarre feature of C/C++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will start from your last question

> Also, why doesn't the compiler or IDE complain about main() not
>   returning an int?

According to the C++ Standard (6.6.1 main function)

> 5 A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main
>   function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and
>   calling std::exit with the return value as the argument. **If control
>   flows off the end of the compound-statement of main, the effect is
>   equivalent to a return with operand 0** (see also 18.3).

And relative to this question

> How is this possible, since y = 5 is not a calculable expression?

From the C++ Standard (8.18 Assignment and compound assignment operators)

> 1 The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators
>   all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left
>   operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand.

Sp this declaration

```
int x{ y = 5 };
```

can be equivalently split into two statements

```
y = 5;
int x{ y };
```

Moreover in C++ you can even to make a reference to the variable y the following way

```
int &x{ y = 5 };
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int y;
    int &x{ y = 5 };    

    std::cout << "y = " << y << '\n';

    x = 10;

    std::cout << "y = " << y << '\n';
}
```

Its output is

```
y = 5
y = 10
```

You may this declaration

```
int x{ y = 5 };
```

rewrite also like

```
int x = { y = 5 };
```

However take into account that there is a difference between these (looking similarly as the above declarations) two declarations.

```
auto x{ y = 5 };
```

and

```
auto x = { y = 5 };
```

In the first declaration the variable `x` has the type `int`. 
In the second declaration the variable `x` has the type `std::initializer_list<int>`.

To make the difference more visible see how the values of the objects are outputted.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int y;
    auto x1 { y = 5 };  

    std::cout << "x1 = " << x1 << '\n';

    auto x2 = { y = 10 };   

    std::cout << "*x2.begin()= " << *x2.begin() << '\n';

    std::cout << "y = " << y << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
x1 = 5
*x2.begin()= 10
y = 10
```

Answer (score 16):

> How is this possible, since y = 5 is not a calculable expression?

It is an assignment, and assignments yield values, i.e. the "cv-unqualified type of the left operand", see [[expr.ass/3]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#3). Hence `y = 5` results in `y`, which is `5`, which is used to initialize `x`.

With respect to your second question, see cppreference on [main](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) (or [[basic.start.main/5]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#5)):

> The body of the main function does not need to contain the `return` statement: if control reaches the end of main without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0;`.

Hence, compiler or IDE warning you about a missing `return` statement at the end of `main` would be plain wrong. Admittedly, the fact that you should always `return` objects from non-`void` functions *execpt `main`* is kind of... well, for historical reason I guess.

Comment: An expression can _result_ in a value, but only a function can `return` one. -pedantic

Comment: I think this int x{y=5};  statement is  not valid in c

Comment: @bhura - the question is about C++, not C

Comment: Perhaps worth to mention that, even if not required, still returning a value from main usually is considered good practice?

Answer (score 4):

The `operator=()` results in a value, which is the value assigned to the variable. Because of this, it is possible to chain assignments like this:

```
int x, y, z;
x = y = z = 1;
```

Comment: The **assignment expression** has a **value**. Functions have return values; expressions do not.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at [the documentation on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment), you'll see that `operator=()` return a reference to the object that was assigned. Therefore, a assignment can be used as an expression that returns the object that was assigned.

Then, it's just a normal assignment with braces.