# How to add pointer semantics into C++ STL?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, deque

I am working on C++ STL recently, and I will discuss an example using `deque`. Note that `deque` is just an example, we could also use `vector` or others.

#### Background

The minimal reproducible example is a simple multi-queue producer-consumer problem. Consider a smart washer who can do the laundry itself, and a smart dryer who can take the clothes from the washer and dry them. The washer can be considered a queue of multiple unwashed clothes, while the dryer can be considered as a queue of washed clothes.

Let `class Clothes` be a unit of clothes. The producer will keep generating `Clothes` and add them to the washer queue. When the washer finishes one `Clothes`, it will remove it and add it to the dryer queue.

#### Question

If we were to do this in C, it would be simple by using pointers (`malloc()`) and a linked list. By moving the pointers around we are guaranteed that no duplicated `Clothes` are allocated. When we finished, we could simply call `free()`.

Can we do the same thing in C++ STL? What would be the recommended approach to achieve that?

#### What I have tried and what makes me confused

I ran some tests and found that C++ STL handles the memory allocation and deallocation itself, which makes me really confused.

For instance, (suppose we use `deque` in this case):

```
std::deque<Clothes> washer = {...}; // only 1 object 
std::deque<Clothes> dryer; // empty

// case 1: copy constructor is invoked, 2 memory locations occupied
Clothes c = washer.front();

washer.pop_front(); // destructor is invoked, I think this corresponds to the original Clothes
```

The above invokes the copy constructor and results in 1 duplicated copy. The operation `pop_front()` implicitly invokes the destructor of the `Clothes` object. But it will not influence `c` as it is constructed by the copy constructor. Now, the number of `Clothes` is still one.

```
// case 2: copy constructor is not invoked
Clothes &c = washer.front();

washer.pop_front(); // destructor is invoked again, but there is only one Clothes object
```

The above code obtains the first object in `washer` by reference, and the copy constructor is not invoked. I would assume that there is still only one `Clothes` object now. However, when we call `pop_front()`, the destructor of `Clothes` is invoked. I tried to access some fields in `Clothes` object by `c.val` (suppose `val` is a field in `Clothes`), and I found that I could still get access to it, meaning `Clothes c` was not destructed. That is why I am confused. Why is the destructor invoked, and which `Clothes` object was destructed?

#### My thoughts

I think case 1 is likely to be the correct approach, but case 2 seems to be correct as well, although some unexpected things happened.

Comment: You can use `std::shared_ptr<Clothes>` as an element in your containers.

Comment: Perhaps you have not selected the proper container? `std::list` has a [splice](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) member to transfer elements between lists. It uses the fact that a list allocates each member separately (and not in blocks, like deque and vector).

Comment: Also, there is no rule that a destroyed object has to go away *immediately*. There **is** a rule that you cannot access it once destructed, so you are not allowed to check.

Comment: "I could still get access to it, meaning `Clothes c` was not destructed" - no, that's not a valid conclusion. As in C, attempting to access a nonexistent object has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @molbdnilo By "could still get access to it" I mean I printed out the value and it was correct.

Comment: @EthanL. Yes. As the old saying goes, undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @EthanL. In your second example you have a reference to an object that has been destructed. This is known as a *dangling reference*. Using that reference to access the object results in *undefined behaviour*. Your conclusion (that the object has not been destructed) is incorrect, you cannot reason about your code when you invoke undefined behaviour because anything is possible.

Comment: @EthanL. Basically you have made the common error of thinking that bugged code must behave badly (whatever that means) therefore code that does not behave badly cannot be bugged. This is not true in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The issues in your code:**

You are correct that in case 1 a copy of `Cloths` is created.
You are also correct that in case 2 `c` no copy is made.
However, in case 2 `c` is a dangling reference to a destructed object, and accessing it causes [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This means that anything can happen, including the appearnce of "working" code.

**A solution:**

C++ offers smart-pointers.
You can use [`std::shared_ptr<Clothes>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) as an element in your containers. This will avoid both copying of the `Clothes` objects and having a dangling reference.
A `std::shared_ptr` manages the lifetime of the object (of type `Clothes` in this case) automatically. It will be released when no longer needed (this is done by keeping a reference-count for each object).
Note that the recomended way to create `shared_ptr`s is via [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

```
#include <deque>
#include <memory>

class Clothes 
{ 
    // ...
};

int main() 
{
    std::deque<std::shared_ptr<Clothes>> washer = { std::make_shared<Clothes>() }; 
    std::deque<std::shared_ptr<Clothes>> dryer;

    auto c = washer.front();        
    washer.pop_front();             
    dryer.push_back(c);
}
```

---

Finally note that there is also [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), which supports a single owner and no copying (only **moving**). However in this case it seems to me that `std::shared_ptr` is more straight-forward to use. If you want to use `std::unique_ptr`, it should be something like:

```
#include <deque>
#include <memory>

class Clothes 
{ 
    // ...
};

int main() 
{
    std::deque<std::unique_ptr<Clothes>> washer;
    washer.push_back(std::make_unique<Clothes>());
    std::deque<std::unique_ptr<Clothes>> dryer;

    auto c = std::move(washer.front());
    washer.pop_front();
    dryer.push_back(std::move(c));
}
```

Comment: +1 for the answer. However, in both examples, the instruction `return 0` should be added at the end of the `main()` function's body. Also, in the first example, the function signature should be changed from `main_()` to `main()`.

Comment: Thanks @LoS - `main_` was a typo - fixed. But regarding `return` from `main` - it is actually **not** required. See here: [Why does the main function work with no return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293642/why-does-the-main-function-work-with-no-return-value).